# Rewrite MySQL query and make it short

Tags: mysql

Can someone please help me simplify the following MySQL query. The query works perfectly fine, but I just want to simplify the query and make it to read easily.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_order_payments 
WHERE customer_order_id = (SELECT customer_order_id FROM  customer_order_payments WHERE payment_code = 'O1529P03N001') 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The table structure is as the following

```
+-------------------+--------------+
| customer_order_id | payment_code |
+-------------------+--------------+
|              1528 | O1528P09N002 |
|              1528 | O1528P07N001 |
|              1528 | O1528P09N003 |
|              1529 | O1529P03N001 |
|              1529 | O1529P03N004 |
|              1529 | O1529P03N003 |
|              1529 | O1529P03N002 |
|              1598 | O1598P03N001 |
|              1608 | O1608P03N001 |
|              1610 | O1610P20N001 |
|              1620 | O1620P03N002 |
|              1620 | O1620P03N001 |
|              1634 | O1634P03N003 |
|              1634 | O1634P03N004 |
|              1634 | O1634P03N001 |
|              1634 | O1634P03N002 |
|              1645 | O1645P03N001 |
|              1655 | O1655P02N001 |
|              1663 | O1663P20N001 |
|              1694 | O1694P03N001 |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

The query will return rows which customer_order_id are all 1529

Comment: I have updated my question so that it's more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `payment_code = '123456789'` condition directly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_order_payments 
WHERE payment_code = '123456789' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * 
FROM customer_order_payments WHERE payment_code = '123456789' ORDER BY id DESC